# Do not trigger page 404 on custom template

Tags: templates

I have created a template and managing all the pages from my `index.php`

```
<?php

$splitUri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if($splitUri[count($splitUri) - 1] === "") array_pop($splitUri );

if($splitUri[1] === 'sitemap.xml') {
    include get_template_directory() . '/sitemap.php';
    exit;
}

global $global_lang;
if (!in_array($splitUri[1], get_accepted_langs())) {
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    $lang = in_array($lang, get_accepted_langs()) ? $lang : 'en';
    wp_redirect('/' . $lang);
    exit;
}
$global_lang = $splitUri[1];

if(!array_key_exists(2, $splitUri)) {
    include get_template_directory() . '/homePage.php';
    exit;
}

if(!array_key_exists(3, $splitUri) && in_array($splitUri[2], ['terms-and-conditions', 'general-sales-conditions', 'privacy'])) {
    include get_template_directory() . '/legal.php';
    exit;
}

wp_redirect('/');
```

But for example if I am going to `/en` I will have a `Page not found` in meta title, wordpress is adding `error404` class to my body and the server is returning a 404.

Comment: Why are you even using WordPress if you're doing things this way?

Comment: Because in homePage.php I am loading a list of Wordpress pages and in legal.php I al loading one Wordpress page depending of the url